# Control.Monad.State found in multiple packages haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

While evaluating the line "import Control.Monad.State" in a Haskell module, GHC gives me the following error:

> ```
> Could not find module `Control.Monad.State':
>   it was found in multiple packages: monads-fd-0.0.0.1 mtl-1.1.0.2
> Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

How do I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have several options.  Either:

- `ghc-pkg hide monads-fd`.  This will cause GHC and GHCi to ignore the presence of the `monads-fd` by default until you later `ghc-pkg expose monads-fd`, but software installed by Cabal will still be able to build against it.
- Use the `{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}` pragma, and change your import statement to `import "mtl" Control.Monad.State`.
- Use Cabal to build your project, and specify `mtl` in the `Build-depends` line.

The first is best for casual hacking, and the last is best for production builds.

These all assume you want the `mtl` module and not the `monads-fd` module; otherwise swap them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I got the same problem for an out of cabal build, I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Both packages implement Control.Monad.State and GHC does not know which implementation it should prefer, so you need to hide one of the packages from GHC. Seems like the `-ignore-package <name>` GHC flag might help you here.