# Control.Monad.Writer found in multiple packages haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, hackage

I tried to import the `Control.Monad.Writer` module like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
```

`ghc` version 7.4.1 gives the following error:

```
Ambiguous module name `Control.Monad.Writer':
      it was found in multiple packages: monads-tf-0.1.0.1 mtl-2.1.1
```

There is a question with a similar problem and a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048953/control-monad-state-found-in-multiple-packages-haskell).

Despite the solution given in this thread my questions are:
Is this the standard configuration of cabal and ghc?
- If so: *is there a reason for the module to be in two packages by default?*
- If not: *what (might have) happened and can it be undone?*

If that matters: I'm working on *Debian 7.3 wheezy* and installed the `haskell-platform` package. Further, I installed some packages using `cabal install`.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is "standard". The reason is a historic refactoring of the [`mtl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) package to accomodate two different styles of handling type classes with multiple parameters, like the [`MonadWriter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html) class : [*type families*](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html) and *[functional dependencies](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#functional-dependencies)*.

The `mtl` package retains the older functional dependencies approach, whereas [`monads-tf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monads-tf) has the newer type families approach.

As there are now libraries in the Haskell ecosystem that use `monads-tf`, it's inevitable that both will end up in the package database on typical installations - I've personally been experiencing it for several weeks.

Comment: Are you finding new packages written with `monads-tf`? I thought it was effectively deprecated by the popularity of `mtl`. Are you able to solve the issue with `PackageImports`?

Comment: I hit this in ghci mostly. As the linked answers suggest, in cabal packages you just need to pick which to depend on. I haven't actually tracked down what pulled in monads-tf, I just know I have it :-)

Comment: From http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/monads-tf, I suspect `MonadCatchIO-transformers` of being the indirect cause: http://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/MonadCatchIO-transformers

Comment: iirc, you can use `ghc-pkg hide monads-tf` to make mtl the default. This won't affect cabal packages, only ghci/ghc.